# Running adb on Ubuntu 11.10 results Permission Denied

Tags: android, ubuntu, adb

I've searched a lot of resources for this problem but none of them helped. So, I've followed this steps http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/device.html#setting-up and after I tried `./adb devices`, and it shows "Permission Denied".

I'm logged as root, and the weird is that on Ubuntu 10.04 it runs fine, but now I upgraded to 11.10 and the problem shows up.

I did this to rules.d also, which is for Samsung:

```
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="04E8", MODE="0666", GROUP="plugdev"
```

**UPDATE**
I did this, copied the android sdk folder to /home/user and set the permission for adb to +x and when I type ls -la ./adb it shows -rwx--x--x.

And then when I type ./adb devices it says:

> -bash: ./adb: No such file or directory

Any Idea?? Thanks.

Comment: Updated my answer from your update...

Comment: You may try this

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9350666/how-to-usb-connect-android-devices-with-adb-under-ubuntu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I copied the folder of the android sdk to /home/<*user*>, and for the problem with:

> no such file or directory

I installed the ia32-libs by using `apt-get install ia32-libs`. Its basically because of some incompatibility.

Thanks.

Comment: It says only after 2 days. LOL