# How to usb-connect android devices with adb under ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, usb, adb, android

Other may have experienced problems with adb debugging under ubuntu linux.

The symptom is the availability of usb connected android devices e.g. with eclipse.
You may test this with

```
adb usb
```

When you get

```
error: insufficient permissions for device
```

you probably run into the same problem like me.
However, I found on the internet some more or less sub optimal solutions

The basic idea is to start adb as root. The solutions I found were cumbersome.

One proposal is to start adb per sudo. An other proposal was to set up a boot script in /etc/init.d

My solution is to give adb the permission to start as root. To do so, switch to root

```
sudo bash
chown root adb
chmod ug+s-w adb
```

security fanatics may propose

```
sudo chown root adb
sudo chmod ug+s-w adb
```

If adb is already running you need to kill the demon to start with root permission

```
adb kill-server
```

When everything went right

```
adb usb
```

should return

```
restarting in USB mode
```

if not, try lsusb th check whether your device is already connected

Comment: Please do not do this!  The authors of the adb program did not intend for its development machine side to be run as root, but rather to use a udev rule to allow access to listed device types only.  Trusting a program more than its authors recommend is a bad idea!  Also, voting to close as there's not actually a question stated, while the topic has already been covered numerous times.

Answer (score 12):

The Google recommended way to deal with ADB device permissions is to create an UDEV rule which would set appropriate permissions on device enumeration.

As per http://developer.android.com/tools/device.html

> If you're developing on Ubuntu Linux, you need to add a udev rules
>   file that contains a USB configuration for each type of device you
>   want to use for development. In the rules file, each device
>   manufacturer is identified by a unique vendor ID, as specified by the
>   ATTR{idVendor} property. For a list of vendor IDs, see USB Vendor IDs,
>   below. To set up device detection on Ubuntu Linux: Log in as root and
>   create this file: /etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules. Use this format
>   to add each vendor to the file: SUBSYSTEM=="usb",
>   ATTR{idVendor}=="0bb4", MODE="0666", GROUP="plugdev"
>
> In this example, the vendor ID is for HTC. The MODE assignment
>   specifies read/write permissions, and GROUP defines which Unix group
>   owns the device node. Note: The rule syntax may vary slightly
>   depending on your environment. Consult the udev documentation for your
>   system as needed. For an overview of rule syntax, see this guide to
>   writing udev rules. Now execute: chmod a+r
>   /etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules When plugged in over USB, can
>   verify that your device is connected by executing adb devices from
>   your SDK platform-tools/ directory. If connected, you'll see the
>   device name listed as a "device."

Answer (score 3):

use following three command its works for me

```
sudo bash
adb kill-server
adb usb
```

Comment: -1 Do not run adb as root